# How do I connect to localhost via ftp wth PHP?

Tags: php, ftp, mamp

Should be an easy question but I don't really have an understanding of how servers work. I am using MAMP/Apache and I'm trying to use this command on PHP:

`$conn_id=ftp_connect($ftp_server);`

then,

`$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);`

It works to type in my URL, username and password to connect to the remote server hosted on dreamhost, but how do I connect to the local host for testing purposes? What exactly is my server called? And what do I put for username and password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MAMP doesn't come with a built-in FTP server. If you want to simulate a FTP connection locally, you can use the FTP server that comes with OS X. MAMP does offer a step by step tutorial how to use it:

[How to: Access FTP with MAMP](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/08/how-to-access-ftp-with-mamp.html)

Comment: Thanks...I'm still confused though. I followed the directions, activating ftp and copying the ip address into ftp_connect. Now I have this error `ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.

Comment: It seems that Apple removed FTP access in 10.7 and you need a server license to run it: [Lion Server: Enabling the FTP service](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4704?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: Interesting...I am using 10.6.8, so I should be okay. But that's good to know for the future. So...any help for me?

Comment: Did you use the current IP of your computer in your local network?

Comment: I think so...I followed the directions from the link exactly, putting the IP address that my computer told me to put.